# Function does not support collation

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to use the UPPER/LOWER function in Snowflake but I'm receiving the error 'Function UPPER does not support collation'.

Is there any way I can use the UPPER/LOWER functions or is there an alternative?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Can you try the COLLATE function for this?

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/collate.html

This suggests that you can upper case a character within a collation to check for items being the same. Something like:
COLLATE(MyField,'en-upper')

Thanks

Ben

Comment: Hi Ben. Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, the results didn't change with this code.

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove the collation from the column by passing an empty string to the *<collation_specification>* parameter of the *COLLATE* function, then pass the result to the *UPPER* function, just like this `UPPER(COLLATE(COLLATED_COLUMN, ''))`

I have tested this solution for some regex related functions in snowflake that doesn't support collation, it's worth a try. See [using regexp_replace for replacing special characters in snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65395203/using-regexp-replace-for-replacing-special-characters-in-snowflake/66962397#66962397)

Greetings from Peru!

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to use the UPPER() function without error (no collation specified on my testing table);

select upper(field1) from ;

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/upper.html

Looking at the documentation for collation, this particular function is not yet supported with collations. To see a list of supported functions;

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/collation.html#limited-support-for-collation-in-built-in-functions

Comment: Thanks for the links. I checked the column type from the table that I was querying from and it looked like it was collated, probably why I was unable to use these functions.