# using regexp_replace for replacing special characters in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

there are special characters in one of column and need to replace with space.
i am using REGEXP_REPLACE, but throwing error as the columns is having collation as 'en-ci'

SQL COMMAND :
`select REGEXP_REPLACE(INPUT_STRING, '[+,()]', ' ',1,0) FROM TABLE;`

below is the error:
SQL compilation error: `error line 1 at position 7 Function REGEXP_REPLACE does not support collation.`

your suggessions may greatly helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to remove the collation from the column by passing an empty string to the *<collation_specification>* parameter of the *COLLATE* function, just like this `COLLATE(COLLATED_COLUMN, '')`
This works for any regex related function in snowflake that doesn't support collation :)

---

In your case, you should be doing something like this:
`select REGEXP_REPLACE(COLLATE(INPUT_STRING, ''), '[+,()]', ' ', 1, 0) FROM TABLE`

P.S: This one was hard to figure out, greetings from Peru!

Answer (score 0):

I confirmed the behavior that columns collated using en-ci don't work with REGEXP_REPLACE. I suspected and confirmed that JavaScript regex replacements in Snowflake UDFs *will* work.

I wrote a set of Snowflake UDFs to approximate the syntax of Snowflake regular expression functions as closely as possible using JavaScript's regular expressions. The point of that was to support lookaheads and lookbehinds, but the same functions will support this use case too.

You can get the UDFs here: https://github.com/GregPavlik/SnowflakeUDFs/blob/main/Regex.txt

You can get brief documentation here:
https://github.com/GregPavlik/SnowflakeUDFs/blob/main/RegExp2_Functions.pdf

You can then run your statements by adding a "2" at the end of the name of a Snowflake regular expression function. It will then use the UDF that simulates that function's behavior but using JavaScript's regular expressions:

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE2(INPUT_STRING, '[+,()]', ' ',1,0) FROM TABLE;
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggesion, i have created UDF as per the given link . but it is throwing below error.
`JavaScript execution error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid flags supplied to RegExp constructor 'g0' in REGEXP_SUBSTR2 at ' var regex = new RegExp(PATTERN, params)' position 16 stackstrace: REGEXP_SUBSTR2 line: 11`

Comment: Can you show how you're calling REGEXP_SUBSTR2? The flag should be 'g' and I'm trying to determine where the 'g0' flag is coming from.

Comment: this is how i am calling..
`REGEXP_SUBSTR2('inputstring', '[+,()]', ' ',1,0)`

Comment: You should be using REGEXP_REPLACE2 not REGEXP_SUBSTR2. This works: select regexp_replace2('inputstring', '[+,()]', ' ');

Comment: still getting the error, when i am giving input string as 'samplestring' (manual string) it is working but with the column name it is not working. `select REGEXP_REPLACE2(Columnname, '[+,()]', ' ',1,0,'') AS Col1 from table;` below is the error `JavaScript execution error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined in REGEXP_REPLACE2 at ' var skippedString = SUBJECT.substring(0, POSITION - 1);' position 32 stackstrace: REGEXP_REPLACE2 line: 6`